# Filter queryset in inline model admin based on parent attribute

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-admin

Orders are created in django admin with ticket inlines. I want to filter ticket zones by event that is selected in order.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True)
    ...

class Ticket(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True)
    ...

class Zone(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', null=True)
    ...
```

[screenshot of order creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YpO2.png)
Was used to add event in ticket inline. How can I solve this problem to get rid of event in ticket inline?

Basically I need to filter queryset of inline model based on selected field of parent model.